# Fail to execute GS script for Imageick

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu

I have a Laravel Application setup on Ubuntu 18.04 with apache2.

Today I got the following issue which comes from imageick->readImage() that I use to generate the image from PDF.

> FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH
>   -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r144x144' -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-19207ziBGob4E6t7W%d'
>   '-f/tmp/magick-19207Gum2Xw9QKD6A' '-f/tmp/magick-19207sU6WmPfGlO5e''
>   (-1) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/462

It was working fine before but this start to happen after I upgrade packages on linux.

Can someone point me out how to fix or where to look for the more detail of the error? My apache error log is clean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem using MiniMagick and Ghostscript 9.26. The solution was to downgrade to Ghostscript 9.25.

https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/472#issuecomment-442389926